# Creating an Event Listener in PHP, awaiting XML content

Tags: php, events, event-handling, xml-parsing

I need to create an event listener. I'm a novice so be kind :)

Basically I am on page1.php (php file); I want inside a loop to go check page2.xml (xml file) for some information which should be received at some point. Either check it all the time, or wait and every 5 minutes or so to see if some information has been received there. Either of them work for me.

If no info has been received after a few minutes, then I want to run again the loop (until it is received), otherwise, move forward and do something with my newly received information. This part I have no problem with, just the event listener itself. I couldn't find the function I should be using anywhere. :( I only need to check and retrieve the content of the xml file every so often.

I am not so sure how I should go about this if there isn't just a function which does this, but I couldn't find much when I searched for "event listener php".

Any help would be appreciated: reference to tutorials/sample code/even just telling me what keywords I should be looking for or what I need to learn first in order to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: How is this file being updated? Is it on your server and some other script is updating it, or are you pulling it from some other server? Are you talking about a long-running PHP script on the server or about polling from a website/client?

Comment: This xml file is being updated by an external server, but it is located on my server - the same one as the php file.

Comment: I am not sure what is "long-running php script" or "polling" or what is the difference between them. This is basically an external API which updates my xml file. My php script should run until it receives this information and does something with it, and then it can stop. Also, this doesn't have to give an output on the website (though it could). This can just be in a php page which was triggered by a form and is now running on its own (if that is even possible)

Comment: a better description of what exactly you are trying to accomplish may be useful. chances are there may be a much easier way to accomplish the same result without the need of all the things that you are describing.

Comment: Okay good idea. I am using twilio api. I send an sms in the php page. Now if there is an sms reply it arrives at the xml page. But I want to use the reply in my original php loop.. thanks!

Comment: How is Twilio updating the XML file? Is it uploading it via FTP to your server? Are you polling it from their server? Are their sending a POST request to your server with the updated XML? The point here is to find an "event" that you can hook into. If there isn't one, you just need to run your script every once in a while and check if something has been updated.

Comment: They are sending a POST request and updating the XML

Comment: So you have a script on your server that receives the file and stores it somewhere? Couldn't you also use that to trigger your update?

Comment: no, i don't do anything to receive it, i just host the xml file and they take care of the updating when the sms comes in; no script on my end receives it. However I am trying to add a post global now which would receive the info from the sms but according to what you are saying I should do that in js?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know how Twilio can alter files on your server without you receiving them and I have no experience with the Twilio API, so I can't give any more hints.

Comment: Thanks anyway! I'll try see what I can do with js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following:

Automatically saved to database every time something new came in.

Then ran a php loop that every few minutes checked to see if there is something new in the database which fits the parameters of this new event (including that it happenned within the timeframe of the past few minutes). I used `flush();` and then `sleep(120);` in the loop to get the loop to keep running every few minutes, until the new info came in in which case it will `break();` or `die();`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you should understand the terminology you're using.  PHP is not an event-driven language, it is a request-driven language.  A request comes into the web-server, PHP parses it and a response is sent back to the requester.  At no point are there events triggered that you can process or handle.  You can implement your own "event system" but ultimately this is much more work than what your use-case entails.

Your best bet is likely utilizing AJAX and continuously making requests to your PHP script until you return the data that you are looking for.  Ultimately you will need to learn about the [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) JavaScript object.  After you understand how to make asynchronous requests utilizing JavaScript you can look at the [`setInterval()`](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) method for how to repeatedly make a request.

Once you can repeatedly make asynchronous requests it should be a relatively simple process of creating a webpage where you can trigger the AJAX requests to be sent.

---

There is no need for a loop in your PHP code.  The loop is effectively done on the other end.  Here's a textual workflow that you might follow:

1. Go to a site designed to trigger your AJAX calls and trigger them.
2. Make your async request to your PHP script.
3. Inside your PHP script open up the XML file and check for the necessary content.
4. Return a response in the form of a JSON object.  One response can mean the data wasn't updated, the other response means the data was updated.
5. Parse the response, if the data was not updated repeat from step (2).  If the data was updated continue to step (6).
6. Display a celebratory greeting that your data was updated or a notice that we are still waiting for the data to be updated.  Perhaps you can have the number of tries as well, off to the side.

Comment: Ok cool I know how to use ajax, I've used jquery's ajax functionality elsewhere, I just thought since this is part of the php loop that it won't be possible? Then I should just run a script from the middle of the php loop?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this writing an inbox parser in PHP. You're best option is to:

Code `page1.php` in which you just need to do 2 things: read XML from `page2.xml` and
   if there is something "new" just execute the data-parsing
   code.

Setup a [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job (if you're under linux) to execute every 5 minutes or so (Cron command is something like: `php /path/to/page1.php`). In the same way, if you're running Windows you can setup a scheduled task and execute the same command. Be aware that the full path to your PHP installation should be in `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: can i set the cronjob to run as part of the php loop in page1.php? i think this case is not like an inbox where the job will run indefinitely, I just need this loop to be triggered by a user, and then run 1-5 times until there is something new in the xml, then stop completely. is that possible with a cronjob?

Comment: @LucyWeatherford yes, i think it should be possible to manage cron jobs (that is create and fire a job to run for five times every five minutes) using `shell_exec`.